# C# DataGridView Checkbox checked event

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I want to handle `Checked` event of `CheckBox` columns in my `DataGridView` and perform an operation based on column checked value (true/false). I tried to use `CellDirtyStateChanged` without any success. In fact I want to detect checked change immediately after the user checks or unchecks the check box.

Here is a description about my application. I am new to c# and making a "book my room" app for a place which provides guest housing to travelers. This screen may explain well what I wish to achieve;

This is a [.GIF of a software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91K1l.gif) which calculates hourly pay of an employee and this photo is an illustration of what actually I want to build:
[image: This Photo is an illustration of what actually i want to build]

Code for displaying my table in `DataGridView` is:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = "select id,cusid,cusname,timein,
timeout,duration,amount,remark from entry";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I added the checkbox column using this;

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "logout";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "Logout";
checkColumn.Width = 50;
checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
checkColumn.FillWeight = 10;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```

Whenever a user logs in from the login screen a new row will be inserted in the table and hence the dgv will be updated, with corresponding users entry.
I don't understand how to link those checkboxes with datagridview I tried celldirtystatechanged but nothing works, what would be the right way to associate the row with checkbox.

Comment: You can handle `CellContentClick` event of your `DataGridView` and put the logic for changing those cells there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can handle [`CellContentClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event of your `DataGridView` and put the logic for changing those cells there.

The key point is using [`CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to commits changes in the current cell to the data cache without ending edit mode. This way when you check for value of cell in this event, it returns current checked or unchecked value which you see in the cell currently after click:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //We make DataGridCheckBoxColumn commit changes with single click
    //use index of logout column
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 4 && e.RowIndex>=0)
        this.dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

    //Check the value of cell
    if((bool)this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == true)
    {
        //Use index of TimeOut column
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = DateTime.Now;

        //Set other columns values
    }
    else
    {
        //Use index of TimeOut column
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = DBNull.Value;

        //Set other columns values
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked just had to add             this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
 to my designer source

Comment: Yes, you can do it using code  as you did or using designer. To add it using designer, you can select grid on designer, and then press F4 to see properties, in properties window, select events from toolstrip and in list of events double click on `CellContentClick`