# How to detect if checkbox changed in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

In a winforms app, I have a cell with a checkbox. Once the user clicks this checkbox, I'd like to know. I have the following code that I've tried in the events below:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mygridview.Rows)
{
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value) {
    isChecked = true;
  }
}
```

I've tried the following DataGridView events with no success since Value is always null when the user is clicking the checkbox. When the user clicks a 2nd or more time, the above does capture all the previous checked checkboxes but it is too late by then. It still doesn't capture the current click.

```
CellClick()
CellLeave()
CellMouseUp()
CellValueChanged()
CurrentCellChanged()
```

Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: [C# DataGridView Checkbox checked event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090190/c-sharp-datagridview-checkbox-checked-event)

Comment: @RezaAghaei: in CellContentClick(), mygridview.CurrentCell.Value is still null.

Comment: @4thSpace The key point is here `this.dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);` It makes the check apply to the column and then if you check the value, it's not null anymore. If you take a look at code carefully you will find it helpful :)

Comment: It is working. The key piece is the CommitEdit line.