# Progress bar for DataGridView that only accounts for one column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, progress-bar

I am having trouble making code for my progress bar, basically I have a datagridview that has to be filled by the user and I would like for my progressbar to increase only when the checkboxes from column 2 are checked (or to decrease when they are unchecked), I've tried the following code so far in the `void norms_TableDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`

```
        int cnt = this.norms_TableDataGridView.Rows.Count;
        int i = 0;
        string A = this.norms_TableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); //"Approved" Cells 

        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            if (A == "True")
            {
                s_Checks++;
            }
       }
       progressBar.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
```

This is making the progress bar increase at a higher rate than it should because, do to the for cycl,e it is counting more than one time the same checked checkbox. Any suggestion would be appreciated since my newbie idea is clearly failing

Comment: You need to move the `string A = this.norms....` line inside the loop. Make it the first line in the `for` block.

Comment: [DataGridView CheckBox Checked event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34090635/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confident there are numerous ways to do this. Below is one possible way to manage the progress bar such that the “checked” check boxes in a grid’s column dictate the progress bars current value.

If no check boxes are checked, then the progress bar would be at zero. If all the check boxes are checked, then the progress bar would be full. If half the check boxes are checked, then the progress bar would show half filled.

It is unclear if the user is allowed to “add” rows. I will assume that the rows are fixed when the grid is loaded and the user is not able to “add” rows to the grid. Otherwise, the code would have to “update" the maximum value for the progress bar when the row is added.

***A small trace of the current code...***

The current posted code is a little odd and is doing a lot of unnecessary work. For starters, the `for` loop looks odd in a sense that this code is executed in the grids `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event… So, this event fires every time a single cells value becomes dirty or is changed. So technically, only ONE (1) cell has changed. It seems odd to loop through all the check box values when only a single check box value may have changed.

I assume this is because the code is not keeping track of the progress bars current value. So, this value needs to be computed every time a single check box value changes. I am confident, there is an easier approach to change the progress bars value even without keeping track of its current value. I am thinking to add 1 to the progress bar when a check box is checked and subtract 1 when it is unchecked.

In addition, it is odd the way the current code is “checking” the value. There is a line before the `for` loop…

```
string A = this.norms_TableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Then, in the `for` loop there is a “check” to see if `A` is “True”?

```
if (A == "True")
```

This is odd because `A` never changes in the loop. If it is `true`, then it will ALWAYS be `true` in the loop. Same for `false`. Therefore, `s_Checks++` will always either be zero or equal to `cnt` when the `for` loop exits.

To fix this, you would need to “change” `A` to the next check box value with each iteration of the loop. However, even with this fix, the code is still checking values that have not changed since it was last checked.
Again, there may be an easier approach.

***A different approach....***

I am assuming that when the grid is loaded, that all the check boxes are NOT checked and the progress bar would start at zero. In addition, when the grid is loaded with data, the progress bars `Maximum` value will be set to the number of (fixed) rows in the grid.

With this approach, the code will “add” 1 to the progress bars value when a check box is changed from “unchecked” to “checked.” And, the code will “subtract” 1 from the progress bars value if a “checked” box is “unchecked.”

To avoid errors, and to keep it simple, the code simply checks to make sure that adding 1 to the progress bars value does not go over its `Maximum` value. In addition, a check to make sure that subtracting 1 does not go below the `Minimum` value.

So, this approach would go something like below. As soon as the grids data is loaded where all the check boxes are NOT checked, we would set the progress bars, min and max values. Something like…

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataSource = YourDataSource;
  progressBar1.Maximum = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
  progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
}
```

Instead of using the grids `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event, I used the grids `CellContentClick` event.

One issue with using the `CellContentClick` event is that when it fires, the cells value has not changed yet. We could easily reverse the checking logic, however, to keep the code in a readable state, I will call the grids `CommitEdit` to update the changes in the grid.

In the event, the code checks if the check box is checked… in this example, the check box is in column 1.

```
(bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value == true
```

If the check box went from “unchecked” to “checked,” then the code will add 1 to the progress bars value and subtract 1 from its value if the check box went from “checked” to “unchecked.”

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value == true) {
      if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) {
        progressBar1.Value++;
      }
    }
    else {
      if (progressBar1.Value > 0) {
        progressBar1.Value--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information and lesson, really helps out a newbie like myself who doesn't know a lot of the meaning/consequences of the code I write.
One question, if there was a second row where there could one be there, for example, the 6th or the 7th row checked, how would I go about it?

Comment: I am not understanding your question… _”if there was a second row where there could one be there, for example, the 6th or the 7th row checked, how would I go about it?”_ …? Sorry, but, this does not make sense to me. Can you rephrase or demonstrate with an example?

Comment: Sorry, i meant second column*

Comment: I am sorry for the dumb question, but in the line `if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value == true)` how do i find out the index of the column i want to make the progressbar evaluate? Because I can't put the code to work and it doesn't give any specific errors.
I am thinking I am just implementing your code wrongly

Comment: `if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)`
`{`
` norms_TableDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);`
` if ((bool)norms_TableDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == true)`
` {`
`   if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)`
`   {`
`     progressBar1.Value++; `
`   }`
` }`
` else`
` {`
`  if (progressBar1.Value > 0)`
`  {`
`    progressBar1.Value--;`
`  }`
` }`
`}`

Comment: Are you meaning you want to check a different column instead of the column at index one (1)? If the check box column we want the progress bar to use is in a different column (say column 2) then, you need to change “both” index values in the code.

Comment: Example if the check box column was in column 2, then change the first line…  `if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)` … to ... `if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)` And change the column (cell) index when checking the cells value to … `if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == true)` … In your last comment, the code will only execute if the cell clicked is in column 1. The two values need to be the same. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: In addition, it may be better to reference the column by “name”, that way it won’t matter which column the check box column is in.

Comment: Sorry for the awful formating, but yes that was my question, I'vetried switching arround with the Indexes but I can't seem to make it work so that's why I was asking if there was a way to check if in fact the column I want the progressbar to depend on is indeed the column of index 2

Comment: Then, change the two parts in the code as I previously commented… if the check box column is in column 2, then change the code to…  `if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) {` … and … `if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value == true) {` … as mentioned, using the column name may make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Filipe,

I'm a little uncertain about your code, but normally I would handle your situation by doing the following:

```
using System.Linq;

var checkedRows = norms_TableDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .Count(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[2].Value));
double allRows = norms_TableDataGridView.Rows.Count;
progressBar.Value = Math.Round((checkedRows / allRows) * 100,0);
```

Comment: Thank you for you response! Seems clean to me, one question, where would this go to? To the progressbar function?

Comment: @Filipe Almeida, This would go in the equivalent of your CheckBox_Changed event handler so that each time the User checks or unchecks a box on your DataGridView, the progress bar gets updated. As I think some others have mentioned, harnessing that event can be a little tricky, but if it would be helpful, I'll update my answer to show what that looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using windows forms, and you decide that you need to read or write directly to the cells of a DataGridView, you should sit down, take deep breaths, and think again if it is wise to directly access the cells instead of using databinding.

People hesitate to use DataBinding, because they think it is difficult, or they don't really know how to use it.

However if you use Databinding to display your data, you separate the data from how it is displayed. This enables you to change your display, without changing your data. You can reuse your data for other purposes, and You can unit test your data without the need of a DataGridView.

Apparently you have a DataGridView that shows rows of similar items. Let's say `Reports`. You'll need a class Report. I don't know much about the report, only that apparently it has something that can be displayed as checked/not checked: a Boolean property.

The other properties I just invented for the example.

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Author {get; set;}
    public DateTime PublicationDate {get; set;}

    public bool IsRead {get; set;}   // will be a checkbox in the datagridview
}
```

Using visual studio designer you have added a DataGridView, and some columns. Maybe all columns, or maybe you are not interested in the PublicationDate, or the Author.

```
DataGridView reportView =  new DataGridView();
DataGridViewColumn columnId = new DataGridViewColumn()
columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Report.Id);
DatagridViewColumn columnTitle = new DataGridViewColumn();
columnTitle.DataPropertyName = nameof(Report.Title);
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn columnIsRead = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
columnIsRead.DataPropertyName = nameof(Report.IsRead);
// TODO: add the columns to reportView.Columns.
```

Now suppose you have a method to fetch the reports:

```
private IEnumerable<report> FetchReports()
{
    ...
}
```

Now all you have to do is assign the fetched reports to the DataSource:

```
private void DisplayReports()
{
    this.reportView.DataSource = this.FetchReports();
}
```

And presto! All reports are in the DataGridView.

However, this is one direction. If the operator changes anything, then they are not reflected in the original data. If you want two way changes, you need to use an object that implement IBindingList, like [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=net-5.0).

Good practice is to add the following lines to your Form:

```
public BindingList<Report> DisplayedReports
{
    get => (BindingList<Report>)this.reportView.DataSource;
    set => this.reportView.DataSource = value;
}

public Report CurrentReport => (Report)this.reportView.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem;

public IEnumerable<Report> SelectedReports => this.reportView.SelectedCells
    .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
    .Select(cell => (Report)cell.OwningRow.DataBoundItem)
    .Distinct();
```

The Distinct in the end is in case you have selected two cells in one row.

Usage:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, ...)
{
    // initialize the datagridview
    this.DisplayedReports = new BindingList<Report>(this.FetchReports().ToList());
}
```

While the operator add / remove / changes displayed Reports, the BindingList is automatically update.

After a while the operator indicates that he finished editing:

```
private void ButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<Report> reports = this.DisplayedReports;
    // Todo: if desired: find out which reports are added / removed / changed
    this.ProcessEditedReports(reports);
}
```

Note: because you separated the view from your data, the operator can rearrange columns, sort the rows etc, without you having to care about on what row the Report with Id 25 is shown.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Trully I don't know most of the knowledge required to achieve your solution(s), you gave me plenty of topics to look into and to learn about, thanks once again